# FormsAuthentication Rememberme

Tags: asp.net

I am using forms authentication and the I wanted the remember me functionality.
How can I just retain the username alone.

I wanted the username to be stored on cookies and when the user is logged out. I want to user name to be displayed on the username text box.

Is there an example that can be provided?

Comment: If my answer helped you, feel free to accept it. If it didn't, feel free to ask any further questions you might have.

Answer (score 2):

In the login method (Probably your "Login" button click):

```
Response.Cookies["userName"].Value = txtUserName.Text;
```

Then on the Page_Load check for that cookie and assign the textbox a value.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Cookies["userName"])) {
   txtUserName.Text = Request.Cookies["userName"];
}
```

Comment: Hi Chuck, I've got the same question; however, right now whenever I click the `Login` button, Microsoft's `Login Control` handles all of the log in. If I use your method and add an event handler to the `OnClick` event, will I break the Microsoft functionality just to store a cookie?